# Function template and regular overloads

Tags: c++, overload-resolution, function-templates

The following code has a couple of regular function overloads, and - now - a template function intended as a catch-all if no overload is suitable.

It *almost* works as I want, except that using derived classes (which previously ended up in the regular overload) get handled by the function template instead.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base { };
class AnotherBase { };

class Derv : public Base{ };

class Derv2 : public Base { };

class DervDerv : public Derv { };

void f(const Base &b)
{
  printf("b(Base)\n");
}

void f(const Derv &b)
{
  printf("b(Derv)\n");
}

template<class T> void f(const T& t)
{
  printf("b(template)\n");  
}

int main() {
    f(Base());
    f(AnotherBase());
    f(Derv());
    f(Derv2());
    f(DervDerv());

    return 0;
}
```

So the output I get is this...

```
b(Base)
b(template)
b(Derv)
b(template)
b(template)
```

... when what I'd naively expected was this:

```
b(Base)
b(template)
b(Derv)
b(Base)
b(Derv)
```

Is a function overload of a base class really ranked as "lower quality" than a function template? If so, is there an easy way to change this?

https://ideone.com/jD2lgz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not about "quality". It's about conversions, just like it is with any other overload. To do overload resolution on the call to `f(Derv2());`, a compiler will synthesize a declaration like this one from your function template:

```
void f(const Derv2& t);
```

Which it pits against the other declared overloads. This overload gets picked for the exact same reason `f(const Derv &)` is a better match than `f(const Base &)` when you write `f(Derv());`.

A "catch-all" template will do just that, it will catch everything for which there isn't an exact user-defined overload. If you want to prevent that, you need to constrain the template with meta programming. A simple trick that relies on SFINAE would look like this:

```
template<class T>
auto f(const T& t) -> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_convertible<T*, Base*>::value>
{
  printf("b(template)\n");  
}
```

That produces the [exact output you expected](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ba71031768c2a9c). Though obviously, you'd need to know what to constrain against in advance.

Comment: Thanks. Forgot to mention I'm stuck in a C++03 world, so I think your suggestion won't work. Would replacing the regular overloads with template specializations help?

Comment: @Roddy - No. The primary would still be a better match, because the arguments will match exactly. The overloads turned specializations won't even be considered. As a matter of fact, you would probably be worse off. Specializations don't participate in overload resolution.

Comment: As for C++03, this can be adapted. Boost had enable_if for ages before it was added to the standard library. And it's dead simple to implement. As is `std::is_convertible<T*, Base*>::value`, which can be used instead of `is_base_of`. Look those up.